# Can I easily style an input control?

Tags: css, height

Is it easily, straightforwardly possible (no heroic measures: do not revive -- it's not *that* important) to style an `input type="text"` control? I'd like to match its height to the `font-size:70%;` height of the label beside it.

I've tried the obvious: `input style="height:70%;"` but no joy.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the size of the input itself to be the size of the label, or the text inside the input to match the label?

Comment: @Harpyon -- I'd like to try it both ways and see how it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If am not mistaken, `font-size:70%` will do the trick.  But am not 100% sure.

Comment: You're almost exactly right. If the input control has a class, say `wt`, then you say `input.wt { font-size:70%; }` Thanks!

Comment: using font-size: 70% does "work" but it also decreases the font-size (as one would expect).  I want to adjust the height of the input control without changing the font-size - is this possible?